# How to let user customize menu keyequivalents

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu

In my cocoa OSX app I have defined a main menu with key equivalents using interface builder. Occasionally I get user requests for being able to customize these key equivalents. I know users can (re-)define shortcuts for an app via Mac OSX System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcuts, but this is rather cumbersome if you'd want to redefine many shortcuts. What is the common way of showing all available actions (menu items) and letting  a user customize the associated key equivalents? I could brew my own, but would like to know if there are solutions ready available. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I use SRRecorder, and it works very well, and sounds like it'll do what you are looking for.

https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder

Comment: Thanks, however, as far as I can see, this does not offer a way to automatically list all commands available in the main menu and assign new key equivalents?

Comment: Wouldn't you know what those commands are?  so you can manually add them yourself to the ShortcutRecorder, so they are available to be changed by the user?

Comment: Of course I know the commands, but I was looking for something that does all this for me.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have asked an obvious question. I think you're going to have to manually create shortcut recorders for each of those menu options, unfortunately

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll see if the SRRecorder can help once I have done that.